# количество строк в sql

Tags: php, html, sql

Можно ли на вебстранице отоброжать динамически количество строк в таблице, так чтоб не требобвалось перезагружать страницу или нажимать на button?
Например что то вроде:
tab1 : 456
teb2: 23

Comment: Можно, конечно.. Либо делать через вебсокет, либо через ajax чекать кол-во, к примеру, каждые 30 сек (исп. [setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval) ).

Comment: а если надо выводить результат php файла?

Comment: @maloi А количество строк в таблице у вас прям динамически меняется? То есть сидят несколько человек и вставляют строки и им очень надо знать сколько там строк именно в эту секунду? Почитайте про [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) (ajax), но кажется, сейчас вам этим рано заморачиваться.

Comment: начал читать и понял что пока рано, поэтому и ищу более простой способ

Comment: @maloi нет более простого способа (так-то этот способ и так проще некуда..). Я бы вам посоветовал не забивать голову подобным и для начала сделать всё статическим, а потом уже довешивать можно на страницы динамические фичи. В процессе придёт и понимае

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Считайте оконной функцией `COUNT`, например:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) OVER () AS count FROM t)
WHERE col1 = 123;
```

Comment: Вопрос про то, как динамически получать это значение на вебстранице.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ну их же посчитать надо для этого.Или зачем в заголовке sql?